# PDF/CDF of max-min type random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, correlation, order-statistics

For i.i.d. random variables, we may write the CDF of $t=\max(t_1,\cdots,t_N)$ as 
$$F_t(t)=F_{t_i}(x)^n$$
and the CDF of $x=\min(x_1,\cdots,x_N)$ as 
$$F_x(x)=1-(1-F_{x_i}(x))^n$$

When we have $X=\max(\min(\cdots),\cdots,\min(\cdots))$, we may combine above results if every entry in $\min(\cdots)$ are independent to each other in each $\min$ term.

However, I have some common terms in $\min(\cdots)$ terms. For example: 
$$X=\max(\min(x_1,x_2,x_3),\min(x_1,x_4,x_5),\min(x_5,x_6,x_7),\min(x_3,x_6,x_8))$$
I understand that there are correlations, but I am not sure how I can apply, specially for the general case.

Can someone guide me to derive $F_X(x)$?

Comment: The same question, with more work shown, was [posted on on stats.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/210074/6633) by a different user three months ago.

Comment: I am not sure how it helps for this problem.